# Does $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{2})$ have the same number of conjugacy classes as $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p}[t]/t^{2})$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, conjugacy-classes

Let $p$ be a prime; $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is the field with $p$ elements
and $\mathbb{F}_{p}[t]$ the ring of polynomials in $t$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

> Does $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{2})$ have the same number of conjugacy classes as $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p}[t]/t^{2})$?

When $p$ does not divide $n$ this follows from a theorem of P. Singla (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3696)). Note that the case when $p$ divides $n$ in this paper has a gap (see Section 5 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05043)). In fact, when $p$ does not divide $n$, we have the stronger statement that the number of irreducible characters of degree $d$ is the same for both groups, for every $d$. However, we do not know the answer to the question in the title in general when $p$ divides $n$.

One can check that the answer is yes when $p=n=2$ (10 conjugacy classes)
and for $p=n=3$ (127 conjugacy classes), using GAP (the $n=2$ case
can also be done by hand), but for $n=4$, $p=2$ I don't know the
answer, mainly because the only way I know to create the group over
$\mathbb{F}_{p}[t]/t^{2}$ in GAP is via generators, and this seems
to be very computationally inefficient.

Comment: Are you expecting this to be true modulo larger powers?

Comment: No, this is not true for $\mathrm{SL}_2$ and $p=2$, modulo third powers. However, it may be true for all powers, as long as $p$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Well $SL_2$ and $p=2$ tends to be different as the graded Lie algebra (of the first congruence subgroup) is not $\mathbb{F}_2$-perfect.

Comment: The matrix $e_{14}(1)$ has $2^{16}$ lifts in either group $G_i=SL_2(R_i)$, $R_1=Z/4$, $R_2=F_2[t]/t^2$. In how many, say $r_i$, conjugacy classes does this split in $G_i$? I guess that a computer can check this in reasonable time. If $r_1\neq r_2$ I'd be confident that the total number of conjugacy classes also differs. (I chose $e_{14}(1)$ because typically it has a large centralizer while its lifts have a centralizer that is quite smaller, i.e., does not map onto the centralizer when reducing in $SL_4(Z/2)$).

Comment: Is it correct that in the cases you already checked (notably $SL_2$ and $SL_3$ for $p$ arbitrary), not only the total number of conjugacy classes is the same, but the unordered list of their cardinals?

Comment: @YCor: That matrix does not form a conjugacy class so its preimage doesn't split into conjugacy classes.

Comment: I know, I obviously mean the preimage of its conjugacy class. But indeed every conjugacy class there meets the preimage of the matrix. So it amounts to classifying the preimage of this matrix up to conjugation (even it it's not saturated under conjugation).

Comment: @YCor: I don't know whether the unordered list of the conjugacy class sizes of the two groups agree, even in small cases (I haven't checked). A possible approach to this problem might indeed be through the sizes of centralisers.

Comment: I've checked it in $SL_2(Z/pZ)$ for $p$ odd: given any element $x\neq\pm 1$ in $SL_2(Z/pZ)$, all its lifts in $SL_2(R_i)$ have centralizers of the same size, not depending on $i$ and on the lift (only on $c$), and actually it yields that the inverse image of the conjugacy class $C_x$ (which has cardinal $p^2+p$ or $p^2-p$ or $(p^2-1)/2$) of $x$ splits into $p$ conjugacy classes of the same size (namely $p^2|C_x|$). The inverse image of $1$ is just the 3-dim space of traceless matrices modulo conjugation, so this the same in $R_1$ and $R_2$, and the case $-1$ is similar, so lists are the same.

Comment: I did a Magma calculation for the case $n=4$, $p=2$. Both groups have the structure $2^{1+14}.A_{8}$, and have $240$ conjugacy classes, but they are not isomorphic.

Comment: I also managed to define the groups in the case $n=6$, $p=2$, and they both have structure $2^{1+34}.{\rm SL}(6,2)$, but Magma cannot do the conjugacy class calculation because it cannot compute orbits on a set of size $2^{34}$. But it looks as though the structure of these groups could be easily described.

Comment: In the case $n=4,p=2$, the extraspecial normal subgroups are isomorphic. The groups are nonisomorphic because ${\rm SL}_4(F_2[t]/\langle t^2 \rangle)$ is a split extension $2^{1+14}:{\rm SL}(4,2)$ whereas ${\rm SL}_4(Z/4)$ is a nons[plit extension. (Note ${\rm SL}(4,2) \cong A_8$.)

Comment: Note that it's obvious in general that the structure of both groups is $2^{n^2-1}.\mathrm{SL}(n,2)$, and that the $\mathrm{SL}(n,2)$-module structure on the kernel (of dimension $n^2-1$ over $\mathbf{F}_2$) are isomorphic.

Comment: @YCor: i'm a bit confused by your notation. Derek Holt seems to be saying that each group is an extension (not necessarily split) of an extra-special group of order $2^{n^{2}-1}$ by ${\rm SL}(n,2),$ whereas you seem to say (according to your notation) that the nomral $2$-subgroup is elementary Abelian? Is that what you intend?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes: I indeed don't agree about the existence of an extraspecial normal subgroup. Denote by $J_i$ the kernel of $R_i\to Z/pZ$. We have a surjective homomorphism $GL_n(R_i)\to GL_n(Z/pZ)$. The kernel consists of those matrices of the form $I_n+M$ with $M$ having coefficients in $J_i$, and this is an abelian subgroup of exponent $p$ (using that $J_i^2=pJ_i=0$). Same holds by restriction to $SL_n(R_i)\to SL_n(Z/pZ)$ (with  the restriction Trace$(M)$=0). The only difference I can see when $p=2$ is that the representation on the kernel (of size $2^{n^2-1}$) is not irreducible.

Comment: @YCor: OK, thanks. I am slightly confused anyway. I don't really see why the two groups are not isomorphic in the first place, though they seem not to be.

Comment: @YCor Yes you are right, the $2$-group is not extrapecial, it is elementary abelian with module structure $1+(n-2)$. But, as I said in a previous comment, the reason for nonisomorphism appears to be the extension of $2^{n-1}$ by ${\rm SL}(n,2)$ is split in one case, and not in the other.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson to do it by hand, one checks that in $SL_n(Z/p^2)$, the matrix $e_{12}(1)$ has no lift in $SL_n(Z/p^2)$ of order $p$. This argument works for all $p\neq 3$ (including $p=2$). For $p=3$ and $n\ge 3$, the matrix $(I+E_{12}+E_{23})$ has no lift of order 3 in $SL_n(Z/9)$.

Comment: Actually, in $e_{12}(1)$ can be lifted to an element of order 3 in $SL_2(Z/9)$. It then follows from Gaschütz' theorem that the extension is split, and we have an "exceptional" isomorphism between $SL_2(F_3[t]/t^2)$ and $SL_2(Z/9Z)$, while there's none between $SL_2(F_p[t]/t^2)$ and $SL_n(Z/p^2Z)$ for $n\ge 2$, $p$ prime, $(n,p)\neq (2,3)$ by my previous comment.

Comment: The answer to the question seems to be (part of) the main theorem in Singla https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3696. I don't see any assumption that $p$ should not divide $n$ there, do I miss something?

Comment: @YCor: I have edited the question to answer this.

Comment: @AStasinski is Singla's paper in the case of $GL_n$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5304) also flawed when $p$ divides $n$?

Comment: @YCor: The case $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is fine for all $p$, as is the proof for classical groups when $p>2$. These cases where reproved in our paper in a more general setting.

Comment: OK. So according to Singla, there's a canonical bijection between the set of conjugacy classes of $GL_n(Z/4)$ and $GL_n(F_2[t]/t^2)$, preserving cardinalities. It sounds likely that this bijection is determinant-preserving. So what remains is to understand how these conjugacy classes (of $GL_2$, contained in $SL_2$) split into $SL_2$-conjugacy classes, in either group.

Comment: I guess you mean "preserving determinant $1$", rather than determinant preserving. The number of $\mathrm{SL}_n$-classes which a $\mathrm{GL}_n$-class splits into is controlled by the size of the kernel of the determinant on a centraliser. This seems as hard as knowing the orders of the centralisers themselves.

Comment: Yes, thank you: "determinant-preserving" does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe you should emphasize in the question that only the case $p=2$ is unsettled?

Comment: Sorry to have confused you. By "classical groups" I meant other than type A. The case of $SL_n$ is open for all $p$ dividing $n$ (apart from the small cases mentioned here).

Comment: This is in accordance with the Langlands correspondence as (loosely speaking) the representations of local fields of char 0 and char p should correspond to Galois representations, and by Fontaine-Wintenberger we know that local Galois groups in char 0 and char p are closely related (of course, this is not a rigorous argument).

Comment: Since the representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(R_2)$ have been classified by Singla, isn't it sufficient to compute the $L$-packet in $\mathrm{SL}_n$ associated to each of these? This may be technical but should be explicitly computable.

Comment: @François Brunault: What do you mean by $L$-packet in this context?

Comment: Given an irrep $\pi $ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(R) $, the associatew $L $-packet is simply the set of irreducible constituents of the restriction of $\pi $ to $\mathrm{SL}_n(R) $ (this is just Clifford theory).

Comment: Then this is similar to the approach mentioned by YCor above, because the size of a Clifford orbit is controlled by a centraliser (in $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)$). So it all comes back to matching up the sizes of centralisers. The problem with these centralisers is that they do not always map surjectively onto the centraliser in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have preferred to not answer my own question, but here it goes. Yes, the two groups have the same number of conjugacy classes and in fact, the groups $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(W_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q}))$ and $\mathrm{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{q}[t]/t^{2})$, for $q$ a power of a prime $p$ dividing $n$, have the same number of irreducible characters of dimension $d$ for every integer $d>1$.
This is proved [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869320304701?dgcid=author) (arXiv link [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.09878)).

Comment: Name of the 'here':  [Stasinski - Representations of $\operatorname{SL}_n$ over finite local rings of length two](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2020.08.036).  (Just to mention, I found this and related papers very interesting!)

Answer (score 8):

Oh, I did not know about this ongoing discussion on math overflow. [Amri](https://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/) pointed out to me about this discussion today morning only. As I discussed with you in a private communication, I don't know how to fix this at the moment. Moreover in this [recent article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06570.pdf) of mine with M Hassain, we show that  $SL_n$ for $p \mid n$ even for $n=2$ behaves pretty differently as compared to $GL_n$ (see Theorem 1.2). For example Corollary 1.3 of this article shows that the complex group algebras of $SL_2(Z/2^{2r} Z)$ are not isomorphic to $SL_2(F_2[t]/(t^{2r}) )$ for any $r > 1$. This is weaker than conjugacy class question for such groups, if one is interested in that, but still quite interesting given that corresponding group algebra of $GL_2$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Name of recent article:  [Representation growth of special compact linear groups of order two](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06570).